# Can a Foundation 4 Tab Section be displayed within a Reveal?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having lots of trouble doing this. Basically I have a "Contacts" button. The button works perfectly fine, when you click the reveal comes down but fails to show the Tabs section that I want to be shown.

I tested to make sure my Reveal and button were written correctly by doing this: I replaced the sections tabs with simple

tags and random words. The random words and paragraphs are shown perfectly when clicking on the button, however the Sections Tabs do not get shown for some reason. Am I missing something? Here's my markup for the Reveal including the sections Tabs:

```
<div id="second-modal" class="reveal-modal">
    <div class="section-container tabs" data-section="tabs">
        <section class="active">
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Content of section 1.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Content of section 2.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using foundation-4 and using their example code. It's a basically a straight copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight from the Foundation docs...

Looks like you have to initialize the tabs when the modal is opened.

```
$('#myModal').on('opened', function () {
  $(this).foundation('section', 'reflow');
});
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html

(Scroll to the very bottom)